# Read URI to extract parameters

Tags: android

I am trying to read the parameters from the custom uri and display in the app. I am calling the app from browser like this 
" worklight://this/is/important" 
Now i want to extract the parameters in the android app. I have looked many examples in the web. I tried in my app's HTML page like this:

`Uri data = getIntent().getData();
List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
String first = params.get(0);
String second = params.get(1);`

But i am not successful so far. 
My error log is:

```
Uncaught Exception: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at 
  (compiled_code):72.
```

72 line is basically `Uri data = getIntent().getData();` 
I have tried many ways but i am not successful. Please let me know how to successfully pass the parameters and read them in the hybrid app(worklight, but for now working only on android).

Manifest:

```
        </intent-filter>  
        <intent-filter>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="com.scan.scan.NOTIFICATION"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
            <data android:scheme="worklight"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

scan.java:

public class scan extends CordovaActivity implements WLInitWebFrameworkListener {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WL.createInstance(this);

    WL.getInstance().showSplashScreen(this);

    WL.getInstance().initializeWebFramework(getApplicationContext(), this);

}
```

Comment: Hey i am no sir...Welcome.. :) Happy coding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

`Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
Uri uri = (Uri)bundle.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);`

Comment: I still get the same error with getIntent(); I think placing of this code is also important. could you let me know where exactly i should put this code. I am new to mobile and am not so aware of intents.

Comment: I have index.html which is the home screen for the app. And as how worklight works this html page is loaded from the main java class. Let me know what else is needed. Thankyou for your time

Comment: post some code lines prior to `Uri data = getIntent().getData();` call. in which method you are calling this.

Comment: I donno from which function i should call this. Thats the problem. I tried to call from javascript in the html page and also from the scan.java class

Comment: Maybe you should upload a demo app exhibiting the problem, because it seems you are not unable to properly explain yourself.